# Node.js MySQL INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE doesn't insert/update more than one row

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb, upsert

I have a database on MariaDB (a MySQL-like implementation) with a table like this:

**product_qts**

```
  product_id  |    name    |    value  
-----------------------------------------
       1      |     xxs    |      2
       1      |      l     |      1


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products_qts (
product_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
name CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
value TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY (product_id, name), 
CONSTRAINT product_qt_fk FOREIGN KEY (product_id)
REFERENCES products(id) ON DELETE CASCADE) ENGINE=INNODB
```

I set product_id and name as primary keys.

The DB is accessed through a node.js back-end.

So when the user wants to update a product he submit the new quantities
and then I call this function:

```
updateQtsById: (qtsArray) => {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        pool.query('INSERT INTO products_qts (product_id, name, value) ' +
                'VALUES ? ' +
                'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ' +
                'value=VALUES (value) ',
                qtsArray
            )
            .then(result => {
                resolve(result.affectedRows);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                reject(error);
            });
    });
}
```

The parameter I sent to it is like this:

```
[ [ 1, 'onesize', 3 ], [ 1, 'xxs', 2 ], [ 1, 'xs', 1 ] ]
```

Now it does not rise any error, but instead of insert multiple values it update the first one and then stops. Where am I wrong? Which is the best way?

**EDIT:**

product_id is a FOREIGN KEY

Comment: What content the `qtsArray` variable?

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev sorry you are right, that's it
[ [ 1, 'onesize', 3 ], [ 1, 'xxs', 2 ], [ 1, 'xs', 1 ] ]
i edited the answer

Comment: Try add    `id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,` to Table
Then repeat the same

Comment: @flakerimi but I need that it updates if (product_id,name) is duplicate, how can reach that?

Comment: check this : https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/

Comment: You cant update 3 rows with same id with different data, because it doesn't know which one, so thats why you need id

Comment: @flakerimi it's not working. now i have autoincrement id primary key and a unique key index (product_id, name), the function is the same, but it just ends up with one only update.

Comment: I think it's nodejs implementation. The query `INSERT INTO products_qts (product_id, name, value) VALUES ( 1, 'onesize', 3 ), ( 1, 'xxs', 2 ), ( 1, 'xs', 1 ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value=VALUES (value); ` works pretty fine.

Answer (score -1):

> When you insert a new row into a table if the row causes a duplicate
>   in UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY , MySQL will issue an error.

However, if you specify the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE option in the INSERT statement, MySQL will update the existing row with the new values instead.

The syntax of INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO products_qts (product_id, name, value)
VALUES ( 1, 'onesize', 3  )
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   name = onesize, 
   value = 3,
   ...;
```

AND all this should be in loop

like

```
qtsArray.forEach(function(item) { 

 }).
```

Comment: I can't do a loop on that because I'm using promises and I need to know when it ends.

Comment: You can use Promise.all in this case